# Merge two data frames based on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, frame

I have two data frames looking like that

data frame 1:

```
P.X    value
OOPA     5
POKA    4
JKIO    3
KOPP    1
```

data frame 2:

```
P.X.1   P.X.2   P.X.3  P.X.4    mass
        JKIO    UIX    HOP       56
                CX     OOPA      44
EDD             POKA             13
KOPP    FOSI                     11
```

and I want to merge the two data files based on the df1 P.X and df2 P.X.1,P.X.2,P.X.3,P.X.4. So if it the JKIO in P.X.2. appears in the P.X one then merge them in a new data frame in the same row JKIO, 3, 56 as below:

data frame new:

```
P.X    value  mass
OOPA    5      44
POKA    4      13
JKIO    3      56
KOPP    1      11
```

Do you know how can I do it maybe with

```
merge(df1,df2 by(P.X == P.X.1 | P.X.2 | P.X.3 | P.X.4)
```

?

Comment: In data frame 2, you have blank cells. Are they really blank? Or do you have NAs?

Comment: yes I have, they are blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is one way to achieve your goal. You want to convert `df2` to a long-format data and get rows that have more than 1 character. Once you have this data, you merge df1 with the updated df2.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(df1,
          pivot_longer(df2, cols = P.X.1:P.X.4, names_to = "foo",
                       values_to = "P.X") %>% filter(nchar(P.X) > 0),
          by = "P.X") %>% 
select(-foo)

   P.X value mass
1 OOPA     5   44
2 POKA     4   13
3 JKIO     3   56
4 KOPP     1   11
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- structure(list(P.X = c("OOPA", "POKA", "JKIO", "KOPP"), value = c(5L, 
4L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(P.X.1 = c("", "", "EDD", "KOPP"), P.X.2 = c("JKIO", 
"", "", "FOSI"), P.X.3 = c("UIX", "CX", "POKA", ""), P.X.4 = c("HOP", 
"OOPA", "", ""), mass = c(56, 44, 13, 11)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Sorry I changed my questions because I realized I haven't express myself thoroughly.

Comment: @user12237608 I was just reading your update. I am glad that my code worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do:

```
 df_new <- cbind(df1, df2[,5])
```

Comment: What the df2[,5] means?

Comment: It means that you only select column nr. 5 from `df2`. You can address rows and columns by subsetting the object, by using brackets [ ]. Rows are addressed in front of the comma, and columns after the comma. For example, by running `df1[3,2]` it would return the value 3, since this is the value stored at row 3, column 2 in your `df1`.

Comment: @veghokstvd this works for this example, but suppose df2 has 40 columns, it makes it very long to merge these two df

Comment: @bretauv then you could do `df_new <- cbind(df1, df2[,5:40])`

Comment: @veghokstvd true

Comment: thanks because actually my data are 40 columns each. But I forgot to mention, that the df2 are not in the same order as the df1.